# Next month date not considered

Tags: php

I have this code to switch to next Monday or Tuesday if "next day" is Sat or Sun.

But, if next monday is in March script return to me February instead March.

Can anyone help me to understand where is wrong?

```
    // OP1
$option_1 = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days"));
$dd_option_1 = date('l', strtotime( $option_1));

if ($dd_option_1 == "Saturday") {
         $option_1 = Date($option_1, strtotime("+2 days"));
         echo $option_1;
} 
else if ($dd_option_1 == "Sunday") {
         $option_1 = Date($option_1 , strtotime("+1 days"));
         echo $option_1;
}        
else {
echo $option_1;
}
```

TKS

Answer (score 3):

Your second and third use of `date()` does not make sense:

```
Date($option_1, strtotime("+2 days"));
```

`option_1` is a formatted time string and the first parameter should specify the format like in your first use of `date()`.

If you don't have the date stored but are always using the current date, you could use:

```
$option_1 = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
```

and

```
$option_1 = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"));
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, i check this out now.

Answer (score 0):

There are options available within [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to simplify and allow for specifying a special interval like "next Monday".

```
// OP1
$option_1 = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days"));
$dd_option_1 = date('l', strtotime( $option_1));

if ($dd_option_1 == "Saturday" || $dd_option_1 == "Sunday") {
    $option_1 = Date($option_1, strtotime("next Monday"));
}

echo $option_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use plain old seconds calculation:

```
<?php
$tomorrow = time() + 86400;
$week_day = date('N', $tomorrow);
$out = null;

if ($week_day > 5) {
    $out = date("r", $tomorrow + 86400 * (8 - $week_day));
} else {
    $out = date("r", $tomorrow);
}
echo $out;
```

Simple without tons of strtotime.

Comment: better with strtotime or with DateTime